# The setting ITEM_PIPELINE can't be overridden from terminal

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd, scrapy-pipeline

In my settings.py I have:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'turing.pipelines.InitFieldsNotInitializedPipeline': 299,
    'turing.pipelines.SetNoneIfFieldEmptyPipeline': 300,
    'turing.pipelines.CheckCategoryPipeline': 301,
    'turing.pipelines.CheckContactPipeline': 302,
}
```

And it works great. But sometime I want run the spider without ANY pipelines.
When I run

```
scrapy crawl -s FEED_URI=stdout: -s FEED_FORMAT=json -s ITEM_PIPELINES=[] example_spider
```

I get this error:

```
return d.iteritems(**kw)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

How can I run the spider without the pipelines?

So far I tried:

```
scrapy crawl -s FEED_URI=stdout: -s FEED_FORMAT=json -s ITEM_PIPELINES=[] example_spider

scrapy crawl -s FEED_URI=stdout: -s FEED_FORMAT=json -s ITEM_PIPELINES={} example_spider

scrapy crawl -s FEED_URI=stdout: -s FEED_FORMAT=json -s "ITEM_PIPELINES=[]" example_spider

scrapy crawl -s FEED_URI=stdout: -s FEED_FORMAT=json -s "ITEM_PIPELINES={}" example_spider

scrapy crawl -s FEED_URI=stdout: -s FEED_FORMAT=json -s ITEM_PIPELINES=['turing.pipelines.InitFieldsNotInitializedPipeline': 299,] example_spider

scrapy crawl -s FEED_URI=stdout: -s FEED_FORMAT=json -s ITEM_PIPELINES={'turing.pipelines.InitFieldsNotInitializedPipeline': 299,} example_spider
```

Others combinations
Look in the docs http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Hopefully you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to currently do that, as every argument is being parsed as a string in scrapy, anyway it is worth asking it as a feature [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues)

Comment: There isn't. I post the issue in scrapy's github. https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2018#issuecomment-222182862

Answer (score 1):

I answered on github, but I'm putting it here as well:

You need to escape the `{}` like so: `\{\}`

`scrapy crawl -s FEED_URI=stdout: -s FEED_FORMAT=json -s ITEM_PIPELINES=\{\} -a test_extract_url=http://example.com/ -L ERROR c_example`